# Is polyspace deterministic?

Tags: c, static-analysis

We have polyspace analysing our code and we have the feeling that polyspace is not being totally deterministic.

We are finding that some errors/violations on our code are not appearing on one report, and they show up in the next report withouth actually changing the affected code.

It is true that from report to report, the code has changed, but this is normally only adding comments and changing few routines out of the affected code.

At this point, however, we cannot guarantee we are not changing something somewhere else that might affect, although this does not seem to be the reason.

I would like to know if you have ever had this feeling when using polyspace and to know if polyspace might find some errors once, and skip them the next time and vice versa.

Comment: I don't think anyone here can answer that. You should contact the devs (with possible bug report) and ask them.

Comment: I agree with @user694733, but since it is a static code analysis tool I would be very surprised, if any heuristics are used or otherwise indeterminate behaviour should occur. This is the domain of dynamic (runtime) code analysis.

Comment: Unless you can demonstrate this with an example - [mcve], nobody will be able to reproduce it and so the question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and reading. You can find a white paper on PolySpace here: http://subs.emis.de/LNI/Proceedings/Proceedings110/gi-proc-110-048.pdf
That explicitly states:

> PolySpace Verifier, as an exhaustive approach,issues checks to prove
>   the result of each and every  operation in the source code considering
>   the variation domain for the variables involved in the respective
>   operation

Basically, that means that your changes on the rest of the code might not seem to affect a specific scope, but they do.

EDIT: I would naively tend to think that static code analysis tools are deterministic, but as pointed out in the comments: some randomness/caching can be used to reduce the complexity. Even tough this shouldn't mean that the tool will randomly find errors/warnings

Comment: Good answer, but I disagree about this part: `we can safely think that static analysis tools are deterministic by nature.`. Many tools will cache results from previous scans or handle the exponential state-space explosion by randomization. I agree that the cause of the seemingly non-deterministic behavior is probably changes in other code. Many heuristics are applied to make static analysis scale.

Comment: @MortenJensen Thanks for the precisions, these are valid points. I'll add an edit sectino to adress them

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I will further investigate the info added in the EDIT, as that might be the issue I might be experiencing.